# Twig Assetic Stylesheets Among Several Templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to add stylesheets to an array so that as twig templates extend through a second and third levels the aggregated styles will carry through.

This topic is related to [Combining Assetic Resources across inherited templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958970/combining-assetic-resources-across-inherited-templates)

From **config.yml**, I made a global array `mystyles` so that we can add to the list of necessary styles as we "bubble up" through the rendering process.

```
twig:
debug:            %kernel.debug%
strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
globals:
  mystyles: []
```

The first template called from my action is from **CommunicatorBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Workspace.html.twig** and I've set the specific style for this page called `admin.workspace.css`.

```
{% extends "DJCommunicatorBundle::base.html.twig" %}
{% set mystyles = ["@DJCommunicatorBundle/Resources/public/css/admin.workspace.css"]|merge(mystyles) %}
```

It extends **CommunicatorBundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig** which has it's own requirement `data-table.css`.

```
{% extends "DJSharedBundle::base.html.twig" %}
{% set mystyles = ["@DJCommunicatorBundle/Resources/public/css/data-table.css" ]|merge(mystyles) %}
```

Finally, we load the outermost template, **SharedBundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig**, which has it's own styles to add before all others.

```
<head>
{% set mystyles = ['@DJSharedBundle/Resources/public/css/global.css', '@DJSharedBundle/Resources/public/css/grid.990.9-col.css']|merge(mystyles) %}
{% stylesheets {{ mystyles }} %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %} 
</head>
```

However, it breaks at this line

```
{% stylesheets {{ mystyles }} %}
```

inspite of this type of test that prints the array that I expect in the proper order

```
{{ mystyles|join(', ') }}
```

It seems that the `{% stylesheets %}` tag wants something like the following snippit to work (which is understandably not an array object, but a whitespace separated list of delimited strings).

```
{% stylesheets 
    '@DJSharedBundle/Resources/public/css/global.css'     
    '@DJSharedBundle/Resources/public/css/grid.990.9-col.css' 
    '@DJCommunicatorBundle/Resources/public/css/data-table.css'
    '@DJCommunicatorBundle/Resources/public/css/admin.workspace.css'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Even then, I tried setting a string to such a long value and printing it, but this doesn't work either:

```
{%
    set str = "@DJSharedBundle/Resources/public/css/global.css 
    @DJSharedBundle/Resources/public/css/grid.990.9-col.css 
    @DJCommunicatorBundle/Resources/public/css/data-table.css
    @DJCommunicatorBundle/Resources/public/css/admin.workspace.css"
%}
{% stylesheets {{ str }} %}
```

I feel like the global should be a viable solution, though not currently working.  Hopefully I'm close.  What might fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible right now because Assetic *statically* analyzes your templates to find any assets you've defined there. Supporting these dynamic cases is on the roadmap.

Comment: Dang!  Suppose I'll work on an adaptation to fulfill this need.

Comment: do you have a link on a github ticket or something to follow the status on that ?