# Symfony 2 append Javascripts, just one request

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, twig

I have a layout.html.twig with:

```
    {% block js %}
        {% javascripts 
            'Resources/public/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js' 
            'Resources/public/js/jquery/jquery.namespace.js' 
            %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
```

And I have index.html.twig with

```
{% extends "MichaelMikeBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block js %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts 
        '@MichaelStoreBundle/Resources/public/js/index.js' 
        'Resources/public/js/jqueryui/jquery.ui.core.js'
        'Resources/public/js/jqueryui/jquery.ui.widget.js'
        'Resources/public/js/jqueryui/jquery.ui.button.js'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

I production mode page returns two js files (two requests). Symfony2 merges two files from layout and outputs as one request and it does the same for index - it merges 4 files and outputs as another request.

My question is: **Is is possible to have layout and index files like in my example output all js as one request?** Or at least append javascripts from index file into layout...

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949548/twig-assetic-stylesheets-among-several-templates). From there: it's impossible right now.

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike I'm facing the same issue. what's the solution for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to remove the call to `{{ parent() }}`, copy the parent asset definition to the template, and add more inputs there.

```
{% extends "MichaelMikeBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block js %}
    {% javascripts 
        'Resources/public/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js' 
        'Resources/public/js/jquery/jquery.namespace.js' 
        '@MichaelStoreBundle/Resources/public/js/index.js' 
        'Resources/public/js/jqueryui/jquery.ui.core.js'
        'Resources/public/js/jqueryui/jquery.ui.widget.js'
        'Resources/public/js/jqueryui/jquery.ui.button.js'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

There is not better support for this because it is not a good practice. The user has already downloaded the first two entries when the layout was first rendered. It makes more sense to set far-future expiration headers than to merge those Javascripts into the child template's.

Comment: How is it bad practice when want to use jquery and namespace plugin in all of my pages? I cant imagine upgrading version of jquery with a new version and update all of my child templates where I should only change it in one place (parent template - layout.html.twig in this case). Each child template should only append "block js" to the parent so that there is only one request instead of multiple.

Answer (score 3):

For insert js files in the twig i write:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{parent()}}    

    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/userprofile.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>  

{% endblock %}
```

*public is in Symfony/web/ directory.*

Is this all that you want?

Comment: no, my example provides 2 requests (downloading js files). Your code will also produce 2 requests (and add one for each additional line of your script). We need to get the code right so that it returns only one request(js).