# Assetic, image assets and caching

Tags: twig, assetic

I am working on integrating [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) into an application that I am building. The application follows the MVC pattern but does not use any frameworks. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) is used for templating.

I have read the documentation and have looked at a few [helpful](http://miller.limethinking.co.uk/2011/05/13/symfony2-using-assetic-from-twig/) [blog posts](http://miller.limethinking.co.uk/2011/05/10/symfony2-using-assetic-for-css-and-javascript-management/).

The application is structured like this:

- application

  - twig_templates
  - js
  - css
- public_html

  - js
  - css
  - images

The twig templates are rendered and then returned by the application, so that is quite straight forward. The `js` and `css` folders underneath the `application` folder would hold the raw javascript and css files.

My plan is that combined and minified js and css files would be stored in the `js` and `css` folders under the public_html folder.

Since I don't plan to optimize any images using assetic, they will be placed in the `images` folder underneath `public_html` directly.

Now the question:

- I understand that by using assetic from twig, combined and minified assets can be exported to my public_html directories:

  ```
  {% stylesheets '/path/to/sass/main.sass' filter='sass,?yui_css' output='css/all.css' %}
      <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  {% endstylesheets %}
  ```

  In this case is the `css/all.css` file regenerated everytime that template is rendered?
- To make the application portable (it could be hosted using a virtual host, or perhaps even in a folder) and to ensure things work in a site with routed URLs like `http://site.com/controller/action`, does assetic provide anyway "rewrite" URLs for images into absolute ones (i.e. `images/a.jpg` into `http://mysite.com/images/a.jpg`)?
- Does assetic work when using nested templates?

  `parent.twig:`

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          {% block head %}
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css" />
              <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
          {% endblock %}
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

  `child.twig:`

  ```
  {% extends "parent.twig" %}

  {% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
  {% block head %}
      {{ parent() }}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="childstyle.css" />
  {% endblock %}
  ```

  In this case, how can I let assetic know that it should combine `childstyle.css` and `mainstyle.css` and serve it as 1 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for this answer it is not possible to combine inherited stylesheets from parent with child's
[Combining Assetic Resources across inherited templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958970/combining-assetic-resources-across-inherited-templates)